# Unable to send email using cpanel smtp server in nodemailer and node

Tags: node.js, email, cpanel, nodemailer

Hi i am using nodemailer to send email using cpanel i am getting error
{
  "code": "EHOSTUNREACH",
  "errno": "EHOSTUNREACH",
  "syscall": "connect"
}

Following is the code to send email

```
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'hostname',
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: '----domain.com',
        pass: '********'
    }

    var mailOptions = {
        from: '-----@domain.com', 
        to: '-------@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'Order Recipt',
        text: 'html' 
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log("Error type:", error.name);
            console.log("SMTP log:", error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
```

can any body help!!

Comment: Make sure you set `host` correctly and is reachable.

Comment: Host is reachable I have tried to ping the host and ping is going. I am using the host name as mentioned in cpanel settings for email

Comment: How about make some diagnostics ... http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx

Comment: after diagnostics i found this error for testing email server. I am sending email manually and it is going. Following is the error generated by test.                                                                                           {Connecting to ip address

SendSMTPCommand: Timeout waiting for response after 15 seconds.

PWS3v2 16832ms}

Comment: I'm quite sure they blocked the smtp port.

Comment: Just resolved the issue the port number they have used was 587  changing port to 587 got it working. Thanx for your help btw.